# GEE or fixed effect regression with clustered SE

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, generalized-estimating-equations

What should be considered when choosing between GEE for repeated measure (panel) data, and generalised linear models with clustered (on individuals) sandwich variance estimator? For example, change in pain over time (variables: pain, time, pain-by-time-interaction). Seems they both differ from mixed effects models in that they treat the random effects like “noise”.

The reason I ask is that from my limited experience their (GEE and glm with clustered variance) effect estimates/SE are often highly similar. The latter is appealing for versatility; eg, ordinal logic models are not possible in GEE and take too long to compute in generalised mixed models (accepting that conditional and marginal estimates are not equivalent)

Comment: What do you mean by "take too long to compute"

Comment: Won’t converge. With respect, that isn’t the crux of my question. I will think about how to reword it to make it less confusing